# kotlin basic question about class grammar

Tags: class, kotlin

I'm a Kotlin beginner and my code/error is same as below.
As I don't know what I should fix, plz tell me some tips.
Thank you for your help in advance.

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication.Kotlin

fun main(array: Array<String>){
    Car(engine: "A", body: "big")
}

class Car(var engine: String, var body:String){

}
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

To apply default arguments you should use `=` instead of `:` in constructor invocation:

```kotlin
Car(engine = "A", body = "big")
```

You can find more info about named arguments [in the documentation.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to not name arguments at all and just use order, as in Java:

```
Car("A", "big")
```

If you want to name parameters, use `=`:

```
Car(engine = "A", body = "big")
```

Named parameters are best used when there is a reason to do so. Typically with an awful lot of parameters and/or default values:

```
class Car(var engine: String = "X", var body:String = "regular")

var defaultCar = Car()
var bigCar = Car(body = "big")
var alternativeEnginedCar = Car(engine = "A")
var minsCar = Car(engine = "A", body = "big")
var sameCarAsMins = Car(body = "big", engine = "A")
```